# Do all conditioned things arise from ignorance?

Tags: pali-canon

A new friend said:

> *If wisdom is not permanent, then it is conditioned. But all conditioned things arise from ignorance. How can ignorance be ended by
>   something borne of ignorance?*

Do all conditioned things arise from ignorance?

Comment: Might this question be a duplicate of, answered by, [Can anyone explain Sanskara / Sankara indepth?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12691/254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is why it is called ceto- & pañña-vimutti... and not vimutti-pañña (althought most translated as such).

How ever, to actually understand (see for "oneself") it requires the fundation: right view... till right livelihood while the rest would come by "itself". Also wisdom arises from ignorance, yes. One is given to see for him/herself following the right path.

There are some heartwood similes to be found in the text, if after investigation to increase Saddha.

And the general "paradox"'s solution is broadly known: certain food is used to go beyond the requirement (of food), and so with all used conditional things as well. Wisdom is used for liberation, like the whole path's paccayas (requisites, foundations, fundaments, bases...)

And it is not so that "by arising of wisdom the great mass of stress ends" but by total uprooting, destruction... of avijjā ("not understanding").

One may remember also that the boat, Dhamma, eg. "knowing", has to be abounded after having crossed to finally go beyond: unbond.

*[Note: This here is not meant to be used for trade, exchange, stakes... and what ever ordinary gains. If not given to give so, it should be deleted]*